# Docker container can't find file even though I see it

Tags: python, docker

I had a docker image working and then I moved my application into a subfolder (app) and now I get the error: "*python: can't open file '/app/solution.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory*" despite the fact that I can connect to the image and see it with `ls`. What am I missing?

Dockerfile

[image]

It's there when I look with ls???

[image]

Comment: nm my previous comment. I think I was confused by the the indentation in your `Folders:` view on the left side of your screenshot. `solution.py` is in your `app` directory, not in your `tests` directory. It's a confusing indentation.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt. =)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You moved the Dockerfile into the `app/` folder but you still have the `ADD app /app` line in your Dockerfile. Because it is inside the folder you want to "add", you need to change that line in your Dockerfile to `ADD . /app` to have it copy the contents of the folder the Dockerfile is in (the src folder) to the destination folder (`/app` in the container)